# Could food be cooked by putting it in a vacuum and bombarding it with nitrogen at high velocity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, food

Line of thought:

- Hot air can cook food
- Hot air is (mainly) nitrogen moving quickly, bouncing off other air molecules and sometimes striking the food and transferring heat to it.
- So could you cook food by just bombarding it with nitrogen directly?

Comment: Bombarding it with nitrogen how though?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the title? No. If it's a vacuum, it's not full of enough hot nitrogen to make a difference. Slinging a few particles at a time at it will not overcome radiative cooling, no matter how hot you make the nitrogen. (For example, the equilibrium temperature of the dark side of a space station is around 100 Kelvin, even though the temperature of the near-vacuum upper atmosphere is around 2000 Kelvin.)

As written in the main text? Yes. You've just described a convection oven, in which hot air (that is: air whose molecules' average speed is high, but whose average velocity is low) is moved around inside the oven, allowing air cooled (molecules slowed) by contact with the food to be heated (molecules sped up) by contact with the heating elements, while continuously bringing more hot (molecules fast) air in contact with the food.

As you may be imagining, with some sort of nitrogen particle beam, rather than a hot diffuse bath of gas? Technically yes: in much the sense that you could, technically, heat your house by shooting it with a machine gun. Practically no: linear momentum is conserved, and if all the nitrogen is going in the same direction, bits of food are going to be violently blasted in that direction. (By comparison, a hot gas with a slow average velocity has very little linear momentum, because the high-speed particles are moving in all different directions, and momentum adds as a vector, so opposite directions cancel out.)

Comment: Having melted a hole in a silicon wafer during ion implantation, you can certainly get things really hot.